How to use setTimeout with react-joyride for step transitions?
I am using react-joyride to create a guided tour for users, and I want to add a delay between each step to give users enough time to view the tooltip content. Specifically, I want to use setTimeout after each step ends to achieve this effect.
Here is a snippet of my current code:

const handleJoyrideCallback = (data: CallBackProps) => {
    const { index, status, type } = data;

    if (([STATUS.FINISHED, STATUS.SKIPPED] as string[]).includes(status)) {
      setRunTour(false);
      handleCloseInstructions();
    } else if (
      ([EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND] as Events[]).includes(type)
    ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (index === 0) {
          setIsSideBarOpen(true);
          setRunTour(true);
        } else if (index === 1) {
          setRunTour(true);
          setIsSideBarOpen(false);
        } else {
          setIsSideBarOpen(false);
        }
      }, 3000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Joyride
      steps={steps}
      run={runTour}
      continuous
      showSkipButton
      showProgress
      callback={handleJoyrideCallback}
      disableOverlayClose={true}
    />
  );
};


The issue I’m facing is that I am unsure how to properly use setTimeout to ensure that the next step is automatically triggered after the delay.
I have already tried using setTimeout in the callback function, but the result is not as expected. I would appreciate any suggestions or example code that could help me resolve this issue.
